# How to calculate age in years from dob in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dob = new DateTime();
        textBox1.Text = dob.ToString();
        int age;
        age = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
        age = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dob.DayOfYear)
            age = age - 1;

    }
```

How to claculate the age from dob.This is my form1.cs.any ideas please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can calculate it using TimeSpan like:

```
DateTime dob = .....
DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan ts = Today - dob;
DateTime Age = DateTime.MinValue + ts;


// note: MinValue is 1/1/1 so we have to subtract...
int Years = Age.Year - 1;
int Months = Age.Month - 1;
int Days = Age.Day - 1;
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1289294.aspx/1

Comment: In my testing there are certain dates which this produces incorrect results for :( E.g., try calculating somebody's age on 2017-01-12 when that person was born on 1996-01-13. The above code returns an age of 21 instead of 20, however their 21st birthday should be tomorrow.

Answer (score 10):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

int age = today.Year - bday.Year;

if (bday > today.AddYears(-age))
 age--;
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]:** To account for leap years use [365.242 instead of 365](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=days%20in%20a%20year&qscrl=1). You should be good [till the year 2799 I believe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

DateTime has an operator overload, when you use the subtract operator you get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instance.

So you will just do:

```
DateTime dob = ..
TimeSpan tm = DateTime.Now - dob;
int years = ((tm.Days)/365);
```

Your code should ideally look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dob = //get this some somewhere..
    textBox1.Text = dob.ToString();
    TimeSpan tm = (DateTime.Now - dob);
    int age = (tm.Days/365) ;
}
```

The TimeSpan structure represents a time interval, it has properties like `Days`,`Hours`,`Seconds` etc so you could use them if you need.

Comment: There is no `Years` property for `TimeSpan`

Comment: @Habib Updated answer. I don't think the downvote was called for, I just threw in an answer that was sufficient for the OP while I was fleshing it out. :/

Comment: `I just threw in an answer that was sufficient for the OP while I was fleshing it out` - It shouldn't be this way, your earlier answer was not even compiling that is why the downvote, now I have removed my downvote

Comment: I think a wrong answer deserves a down vote, now if he did not remove it after you corrected your error that would be uncalled for. (BTW, there is not 365 days in a year, go ask [Fredric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Penzance) how old he is)

Comment: Alright fair enough :)

Comment: in tm.years  years is not displaying

Comment: lol @DilipanK, Hit refresh on this page.

Comment: yea I apologize for shooting an answer so quickly :(

Comment: How to convert into years

Comment: @DilipanK hey I updated my question. Please refresh your page

Comment: By hard coding 365 you aren't allowing for leap years.

Comment: This algorithm (even when you divide by 365.242 to account for leap years) also produces incorrect results for certain dates. On 2017-01-12, the age of a person who was born on 1976-01-13 is actually 40, but this algorithm calculates it as 41.